# Providing Q_PROPERTY in subclass of Q_OBJECT result in Error 1

Tags: c++, qt

I need your help solving the following problem:

I have a base class, that derives from QObject and has the `Q_OBJECT` macro. In another class i want to subclass the base class and provide properties for the use in qml (`Q_PROPERTY`).

But it seems that i am missing a very basic piece of information, because i cannot get this going

**Baseclass:**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <QObject>

class A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT    
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName CONSTANT)
...
```

**Subclass:**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "classpath/A.h"
class B: public A
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString type READ getType WRITE setType NOTIFY typeChanged)
...
```

Furthermore i have registered the type for qml `qmlRegisterType<B>("CustomClasses",1,0,"B");`

In the qml file i am simply creating an B item `B{ type: "B" }`

The error i get is the following: `[debug/moc_b.cpp] Error 1`

Not very informative for me and my Qt knowings

If i remove the `Q_OBJECT` macro i geht `Cannot assign to non-existent property type`

I hope one of you can explain what im doing wrong!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to find the actual error message, in the compile output. Also showing minimal compilable code would help, problem may well be in part not shown, such as constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints! 
I finally figured out that i forgot to put`void typeChanged()` under `signals:`
pretty trivial in retrospect

Thanks at manni66! I had no idea that there is a more detailed compiler output in my IDE. This led me to the correct solution.